# How to remove dynamic control value?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, webforms

Please see the code below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="Div1" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create a TextBox" />
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Erase TextBox Text" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
..........................................
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Request.Params.ToString().IndexOf("Button1") > 0)
            {
                CreateTextBox();
            }
            else
            {
                if (Request.Params.ToString().IndexOf("Button2") > 0)
                {
                    TextBox txtbx = CreateTextBox();
                    txtbx.Text = "";
                }
            }
        }        
    }

    TextBox CreateTextBox()
    {
        TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
        Div1.Controls.Add(txtbx);

        return txtbx;
    }
```

On PostBack, I check if 'Button1' or 'Button2' was pressed.
I press **Button1** and a TextBox is dynamically created.
I enter some text in the TextBox and press Button1 again. The TextBox is recreated and the text I entered is preserved on PostBack.
When I press **Button2**, I want to recreate the TextBox, but I want to remove the text I previously entered. But even though I've specified *txtbx.Text = ""* the text is still preserved after PostBack.
How do I recreate the TextBox but remove the text entered?
*(I want the text to be preserved if I push Button1, but not if I push Button2)*

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the `page load`, your context is not restored yet. If you want to override the state value of your control, handle the `Click` event of each button and do the logic accordingly.